# Performance comparison of In and Exists

Tags: sql

I want to know which one of the following - **Exists**, or **In**, is faster, and why. I have done lots of Googling, and the consensus looks like that **In** is more efficient when the outer query has a large data-set and the inner query returns a small one, while **Exists** is faster for the reverse case. In fact the article at the link [Oracle Tips](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-the-difference-between-in-and-exists-in-subqueries/5297080) say that it happens because in case of **Exists**, the outer query is run first, while in case of **In**, the inner query is run first. If it is so, can anyone explain why?

Comment: To find out which is fastest you can try both and time them.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have any knowledge regarding benchmarking/profiling, stuff that are used to compare subtle differences between similar commands. That's why I asked. May be I will find that one is faster than the other. What I want to know is why.

Comment: Implementation dependant. In SQL Server they both get the same plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Oracle documentation you have a deep explanation on how to [generate and use execution plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optplanmgmt.htm) Also [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle11g_sql_plan_management.htm) you have more information and at the end more links to guide you on the task. But at the end everything will be just spending a couple of hours doing your own research, executing queries and comparing times, execution plans and other known performances issues.